# Why do I get the error: syntax error, unexpected 'in_array'? I am trying to find out if a variable is in an array

Tags: php, arrays, syntax-error

In my PHP script, I need it to check to see if a variable is in an array. A quick search on Google brought up [this](http://uk.php.net/in_array). I put this into my code (I have pasted what I out bellow) but annoyingly I am returned with an error.

```
$dropdown = bool in_array ( mixed $topicid , array $dropval [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
```

The error that I am returned with is:

```
[14-Jan-2015 14:49:25 Europe/London] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'in_array' (T_STRING) in /home/sinergqx/public_html/pages/new_ticket.php on line 34
```

`Line 34` is the line that I wrote to check to see if `$topicid` was in the array called `$dropval`.

I'm really not too sure why I am getting this error.

First of all, I tried integrating it into the if statement which I am using to run different things depending on if line 34 returns true or false when checking if the variable is the array. So when I put it all together and ran the following code I still got a similar error. Bellow is the code that I made when I was trying to put it all together.

```
if(bool in_array ( mixed $topicid , array $dropval [, bool $strict = FALSE ] ) == true)
  {
  echo "Acceptable help topic";
  }
  else
  {
  echo "Please only choose a valid help topic. Custom help topics are not allowed.";
  exit;
  }
```

The error that I got was exactly the same:

```
[14-Jan-2015 15:00:25 Europe/London] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'in_array' (T_STRING) in /home/sinergqx/public_html/pages/new_ticket.php on line 49
```

I was wondering if anyone could spot what I had done wrong?

Thanks very much in advanced for any help I receive. It is very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You just copied the function definition from the manual, right?

Comment: @CodeBird No, `mixed` is not a valid type, and the `[]` are not valid at that point

Comment: @Rangad yeah sorry didn't pay attention to all the types. You have to remove all your types before the variables, and the `[]`, then you'll be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write the types of the variables when calling a function. Try:

```
if(in_array ($topicid , $dropval) == true){
   echo "Acceptable help topic";
} else {
  echo "Please only choose a valid help topic. Custom help topics are not allowed.";
  exit;
}
```

Comment: You also don't need to bother with the `== true`; `if (in_array ($topicid , $dropval))` would be fine.

Comment: @MattGibson That's right. I didn't changed it intentionally because I know that some people write it for the readablity of their code. At work I also have to write it this way because of style guides.

Comment: Escape the tyranny of your style guides here! Be brave! [:D](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/12807/make-a-big-deal-out-of-true)